# How to set up OnClickListener on view shown by TransitionManager

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-transitions

I have an activity with layout in `scene_a.xml` that should be replaced by layout in `scene_b.xml` using [`TransitionManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/transition/TransitionManager) with use of [`Scene`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/transition/Scene). There scenes contain buttons. What is the idiomatic way of handling events in the second scene?

#### `activity.xml`

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scene_root">

        <include layout="@layout/scene_a" android:id="@+id/scene" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

#### `scene_a.xml`

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button_a" android:text="A" />
</FrameLayout>
```

#### `scene_b.xml`

```xml
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button android:id="@+id/button_b" android:text="B" />
</FrameLayout>
```

#### `onCreate()` in activity code

```kotlin
// Inflate activity.xml using ViewBinding “binding”.

with (binding) {
    scene.buttonA.setOnClickListener {
        val newScene = Scene.getSceneForLayout(binding.sceneRoot, R.layout.scene_b, context)
        val transition = Fade()
        TransitionManager.go(newScene, transition)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first inflate `view` of second scene, initialize all listeners on this `view` and after that create `Scene` object via `Scene(ViewGroup)` constructor.

```
    val bView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.scene_b, null)
    //set all listeners etc.
    bView.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener....

    val newScene = Scene(bView)
    val transition = Fade()
    TransitionManager.go(newScene, transition)
```